# I'm looking for a crime fiction book. Husband, a lawyer, is killed. His wife is a software engineer. The setting may predate Google

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for the title and author of a book. It's fiction and involves a murder.

I'm not sure when I read it or when it was written, but I believe the story predates the founding of Google. It's all about how data mining will rule the world.

The husband is a lawyer and his wife is a software engineer.

The wife is working on something similar to Google. The husband is going to handle the sale of the software. He gets killed before the sale goes through. She has an important mentor. He stresses how important the software will be - both for power and money. She turns to him after her husband is killed. As it turns out, he is part of the group that kills the lawyer to stop the sale.

Comment: What else can you remember about the book? Was it written in English or translated? Was it set in the US? Was it a novel or a short story? See also [our guidelines on asking good story-ID questions](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/a/779/17). Any little detail might help someone to identify it!

Comment: Set in the US. Written in English. Novel. I apologize for being an "ugly American" and assuming all would take it for a book written in English. I'm not being sarcastic. I forgot that this is a world community. As to novel or short story, I though book precluded short story. I'll do better.